# Including graphics/shapes in my Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm in the midst of my first independent Java project, and I have a limited knowledge of all the libraries at my disposal, but feel pretty comfortable with the language. This project requires a GUI interface with a JTextArea that displays instructions for user guidance on the left side, and a JPanel with some buttons on the right side. On my panel, I want to include a component with a simple drawing -- say, three rectangles of different sizes and different colors -- and add different actionListeners to each rectangle. How should I start implementing this? What kind of component can I add to my JPanel that will allow me to achieve this?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could display Shape objects such as Rectangle2D, among others, in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel, and then identify clicks to the Shapes by adding a MouseListener to the JPanel. If you're going to be sizing various shapes, I wouldn't use a JButton or something similar, but just a single MouseListener or MouseAdapter added to a single drawing JPanel. Shape has a `contains(Point p)` method that you can use to see if any of the Shapes have been clicked.

Specifically:

> On my panel, I want to include a component with a simple drawing -- say, three rectangles of different sizes and different colors

Three Rectangle2D objects can fit this bill, declared in the class that extends JPanel and drawn in that JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. You will need to cast the Graphics object to Graphics2D, and then you can draw the Rectangle2D objects by calling `draw(myRectangle)` and fill them with different color by setting the Graphics color prior to drawing and then call `fill(myRectangle)`

> and add different actionListeners to each rectangle.

Again, I'd use a single MouseListener added to the JPanel. You can find out which Rectangle2D was clicked by calling `contains(Point p)` with the Point given to you in the MouseListener mousePressed methods MouseEvent object.

For more on this, check out:

- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [the Shape API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)
- [the Rectangle2D API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html)

Comment: Nit Pick- Broken link ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JButtons as your rectangles. This makes action handling easy.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ad different actionListeners -> use JButtons.
but you must to change it's view.

All methods, that you can use are here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html
and here
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29)

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of component can I add to my JPanel that will allow me to achieve this?

The JDK doesn't have one, but you can check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) and maybe use the `ShapeComponent`, then you can just add a MouseListener to each component.